# Where is the hidden word?

Tags: word, pattern

Where is the hidden word in the word below?(Yes, there is really a hidden word)

hhiidididdeenidwwwodddrdddrrd

Hint:

> Don't look at all the digits...

---

Hint2:

> Primes is hidden somewhere in the puzzle.

---

Good luck!

Comment: It was a clever puzzle but the reason why this was downvoted a couple of times is because 1) of the seemingly low effort put in the puzzle 2) The hints should be put later 3) The 2nd hint should be maybe weaved in as part of the puzzle 4) I would recommend phrasing the puzzle like this “without any scrambling needed help me excavate a hidden word using a well known sequence”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase ‘hidden word’

> Is extracted from the string of letters if you highlight all of the letters which is under prime numbers if you were to place the standard  1,2,3,4,5 etc. number sequence over it. So the 2nd letter is H, 3rd is I, 5th is D etc, 7th is D, 11th is E, 13th is N, 17th is W, 19th is O, 23rd is R and 29th is D.

Just to show what I am on about:

> [image]

Comment: So… am I right?

Comment: Yes.You are correct.